# Why is there a large deviation in wait time for nginx server

Tags: nginx, openresty

I have an Nginx server that acts as a reverse proxy and a static file server.

My users complain that sometimes the response is slow.

I tried examining the .her file to understand the issue better and found something unusual.

```
time wait on https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com****
[10.00600000781566, 10.09000002155453, 12.657999974526462, 30.81500001040101, 50.140000049091874]

time wait on  https://fonts.gstatic.com/****
[0.8139999584183073, 0.8409999709799933, 1.4160000515654616, 2.3279999482259086, 79.60999999868869]

time wait on my server:
[59.73200001836568, 59.820000056281685, 60.4199999724552, 60.530999979116025, 60.79299996264279, 61.397000021353364, 61.590999948196114, 61.89499994969368, 62.058999961778525, 68.06700001706928, 68.25800005129724, 68.29399997562915, 68.88300005169958, 69.07899998541922, 69.38299999047071, 69.6550000514686, 69.6710000243038, 69.69899996588379, 69.76500002556294, 70.05899996621906, 70.57600003184378, 76.85900000137836, 256.38100003309546, 267.7780000296906, 280.696999967508, 461.3320000257194, 465.38599997801333, 476.49299997053294, 484.6409999888614, 748.1390000376775]
```

As you can see, there is a very large deviation of the wait time in the requests for the same resource. It is occurring in `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` and `fonts.gstatic.com` which is a reputable server,  but on my server the difference larger.

I initially thought this is a caching issue. But in the above wait time, all the requests are cached excluding 1, I checked the `MISS` request `$request_time` in Nginx and it's `0.4` so clearly this is not the source of the issue.

The server consumes 10% of  bandwidth and CPU is not exhausted  (under 40% utilisation in peak time).

Can someone please help me understand why there is such a big variance in the wait time? Is the issue with my server or the client?  How can I pinpoint the problem?

This is my configuration file of the server (Nginx - openresty):

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

env SERVER_BACKEND_NAME;
env SERVER_CDN_NAME;
env SERVER_CDN_SPESIFIC_NAME;

http {

    error_log /var/errors/externalNginx.http.error_1 error;
    
    
  # The "auto_ssl" shared dict should be defined with enough storage space to
  # hold your certificate data. 1MB of storage holds certificates for
  # approximately 100 separate domains.
  lua_shared_dict auto_ssl 1m;
  # The "auto_ssl_settings" shared dict is used to temporarily store various settings
  # like the secret used by the hook server on port 8999. Do not change or
  # omit it.
  lua_shared_dict auto_ssl_settings 64k;

  # A DNS resolver must be defined for OCSP stapling to function.
  #
  # This example uses Google's DNS server. You may want to use your system's
  # default DNS servers, which can be found in /etc/resolv.conf. If your network
  # is not IPv6 compatible, you may wish to disable IPv6 results by using the
  # "ipv6=off" flag (like "resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off").
  resolver 127.0.0.11;

  # Initial setup tasks.
  init_by_lua_block {
    auto_ssl = (require "resty.auto-ssl").new()

    -- Define a function to determine which SNI domains to automatically handle
    -- and register new certificates for. Defaults to not allowing any domains,
    -- so this must be configured.
    auto_ssl:set("allow_domain", function(domain)
      return true
    end)

    auto_ssl:init()
  }

  init_worker_by_lua_block {
    auto_ssl:init_worker()
  }
    
    # Internal Cdn nginx backend
    upstream cdnnginx_backend { 
        server cdnnginx;
    }

    
    # Limits - so it will be harder to DOS me
    limit_req_log_level    warn;
    limit_req_zone         $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;


    # HTTPS cdn server - will later on become our image cdn as well
     server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name  ${SERVER_IMAGE_AND_FILE_CDN_NAME}; 
        error_log /var/errors/externalNginx.${SERVER_IMAGE_AND_FILE_CDN_NAME}.error_1 error;

    # Dynamic handler for issuing or returning certs for SNI domains.
        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
            auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
        }

    # This is for the Config service so we can pass big enogh information on the headers
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    ssl_certificate /etc/resty-default-ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/resty-default-ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key;

        # Enable gzip compression
        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        sendfile on;

        # Serve the compressed HTML file
        location /saved.html {
                root /var/compenion;

        # we need to clean it in the most external service
        more_clear_headers 'Server';

        # this is against CORS policy - we want everyone to be able to access this
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
        }

    location / {
        # we need to clean it in the most external service
        more_clear_headers 'Server';

        return 404 'Nanana';
        }
  }


  # HTTPS cdn - backword competability to mother existing links video.malkali.com
  server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name my.server.com;
        error_log /var/errors/externalNginx.my.server.com.error_1 error;

        # Dynamic handler for issuing or returning certs for SNI domains.
        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/resty-default-ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/resty-default-ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key;

    
        location /Health {
        return 200 "ComasTas";
        }

    
        # This check HealthCheck of caching nginx
        location /Health2 {
            proxy_pass http://cdnnginx_backend/Health2;

            # this is against CORS policy - we want everyone to be able to access this
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
        }

    # this will check the proxy health check
    location /1/Health {
        proxy_pass http://cdnnginx_backend/Health3;

        # this is against CORS policy - we want everyone to be able to access this
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
    }

    # This will pass normal links forward (signed and unsigned?) - should enforce similar links only to pass forward and reduce attacks
    location ~  "^\/(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){16}\/(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}){16}\/(?:.?[^\/]+)$" {        
        # solve the byte-range requestr support
        proxy_force_ranges on;
        more_set_headers 'Accept-Ranges: bytes';

        # solve the issue of gateway timeout
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;

        set $continue_url $uri;
        if ($arg_sig)
        {
            set $temp_cache 1;
        }

        if ($arg_refere)
        {
            set $temp_cache 2$temp_cache;
        }
        
        if ($temp_cache = 1)
        {
            set $continue_url $uri?sig=$arg_sig;
        }

        if ($temp_cache = 21)
        {
            set $continue_url $uri?sig=$arg_sig&refere=$arg_refere;
        }

        if ($temp_cache = 2)
        {
            set $continue_url $uri?refere=$arg_refere;
        }

        # solve pre-flight issue
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            # this is against CORS policy - we want everyone to be able to access this
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
            
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: refere, Origin';

                add_header Content-Length 0;
                add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                return 200;
            }

        # add the header of the request host so we will be able to route insode
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $scheme://$http_host;

        proxy_pass      http://cdnnginx_backend$continue_url;

        # we need to clean it in the most external service
        more_clear_headers 'Server';

        # clear our internals evidence
        more_clear_headers 'V1Latency';
        more_clear_headers 'V1RequestTime';
        more_clear_headers 'ProxyCache';
        more_clear_headers 'S3priority';
        more_clear_headers 'V1internalcache';

        # this is against CORS policy - we want everyone to be able to access this
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: refere, Origin';

        # @@@ For dbg only
        more_set_headers 'start_time: $msec';
        more_set_headers 'total_time: $request_time';
    }


    error_page 404 403 500 502 503 /error-page.html;
    location = /error-page.html {
            internal;
        return 404 "Nanana";
    }

    location = / {
        return 404 "Nanana";
    }
   
  }

  # HTTP server
  server {
    listen 80;
    
    location /HealthCheck {
    return 200;
    }

    # Endpoint used for performing domain verification with Let's Encrypt.
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:challenge_server()
      }
    }
  }

  # Internal server running on port 8999 for handling certificate tasks.
  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8999;

    # Increase the body buffer size, to ensure the internal POSTs can always
    # parse the full POST contents into memory.
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_max_body_size 128k;

    location / {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:hook_server()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to investigate my server itself:

`iftop`:

```
TX:             cum:    816MB   peak:   36.8Mb                                                                                                                               rates:   17.3Mb  24.2Mb  26.6Mb RX:                     272MB           13.2Mb                                                                                                                                        7.76Mb  7.92Mb  8.90Mb TOTAL:                 1.06GB           47.3Mb                                                                                                                                        25.1Mb  32.2Mb  35.5Mb
```

`top`:

```
top - 08:26:56 up 5 days, 22:33,  2 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.27, 0.44
Tasks: 271 total,   1 running, 270 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.6 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31986.2 total,  12924.5 free,   3720.9 used,  15340.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1004.5 free,     19.5 used.  27610.2 avail Mem
```

The server has 1gbps throughput with a strong CPU.

It utilizes less than 15% of the available processor and  less than the 1gbps throughput capability.

How can I further investigate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

All I've been able to get from your question is that

- something is slow
- you are using cloudflare and gstatic.com
- you can't see anything slow on your webserver

I ASSUME that you are pulling in content from gstatic.com at the browser while the traffic for your origin server is routed via cloudflare.

Looking at one or two har files (again I'm guessing here) is not going to tell you anything.

You need to start by adding timing metrics on your webserver log files then bulk analyzing data. You can pill down your logs from Cloudflare and see the data there / correlate that with your local logs.

Comment: I added initial investigation information from my server, Can you please guide me on how to farther investigate and pinpoint the issues?

Comment: Pull down your logs from cloudflare and analyze them.